# What are some core principles and techniques in Unit Test Framework Development

Tags: unit-testing, frameworks

I saw this question: [i am trying to develop a test runner in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532482/i-am-trying-to-develop-a-test-runner-in-python) and the only response was an example of a test runner.  What concepts, techniques or resources are used by people actually developing test runners?  In a nutshell, where do you start on test runner development?

Comment: possible duplicate of [i am trying to develop a test runner in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532482/i-am-trying-to-develop-a-test-runner-in-python)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement a python REPL that nicely handles asynchronous output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437025/how-to-implement-a-python-repl-that-nicely-handles-asynchronous-output)